# Porque KnnImputer no devuelve la tamano que fue dado?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una dataframe que tiene muchas valores que faltan y pensaba utilisar KNNImputer para ver lo que me sortiria:

```
siren,nic,legal_form,num_employees,num,ca_2021,actif_immo_2021,stock_2021,total_actif_2021,dotations_2021,ca_2020,actif_immo_2020,stock_2020,total_actif_2020,dotations_2020,ca_2019,actif_immo_2019,stock_2019,total_actif_2019,dotations_2019,Classe clients,Branche
160020012,29.0,4120.0,120.0,3.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2.0,3211.0
160020012,11.0,4120.0,300.0,3.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,4.0,3211.0
```

Entonces hice:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer

imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=1)
imputer.fit_transform(X)
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
array([[1.60020012e+08, 2.90000000e+01, 4.12000000e+03, 1.20000000e+02,
        3.00000000e+00, 2.00000000e+00, 3.21100000e+03],
       [1.60020012e+08, 1.10000000e+01, 4.12000000e+03, 3.00000000e+02,
        3.00000000e+00, 4.00000000e+00, 3.21100000e+03]])
```

Que es de tamano (2, 7) mientras que habia 22 columnas. Entonces porque KnnImputer no devuelve la tamano que fue dado?

Comment: ¿y la declaración de imputer? por ejemplo: imputer = KNNImputer(numero de muestras) que no estamos viendo cuantas son en tu ejemplo.

Comment: ¡Sí @tincopasan ! Acabo de añadirlo, tomé 1

Comment: ¿y en el dataframe solo faltan datos en una sola columna?

Comment: faltan todas las columnas entre las comillas @tincopasan : `60020012,29.0,4120.0,120.0,3.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2.0,3211.0`

Comment: aclaremos, ¿no hay valores NAN en el dataframe? sino simplemente puede ser por la visualización al mostrar tantas columnas, mira por partes la matriz a ver que valores tiene.